# How do I get my wireless mouse working on my new HP desktop computer?

Tags: mouse, desktop-computer, wireless-mouse

New HP desk computer with wireless keyboard and mouse synced.  The mouse is awful and I would prefer to use my Logitech wireless mouse.  I plugged USB in but it is not working.   What to do?

Comment: Since it is a wireless mouse, did you try clicking the "connect" button on the bottom of the mouse? Did you try changing the batteries? Does the Logitech mouse work on other computers? Does the Logitech mouse work when you unplug the dongle for the mouse and keyboard that came with the desktop computer? We need to know the troubleshooting steps you have taken so far. Please update your question with troubleshooting steps, model of mouse, operating system on computer, and any other relevant information.

Comment: Install the Logitech software

Comment: It all depends on the specific model of mouse you have.  Perhaps it uses the Unifying Receiver, perhaps it uses Bluetooth, perhaps it uses another tech.  Also depends on the Windows version installed - Windows 10 is good about installing up recent hardware's drivers automatically.  Older hardware or older OS means you have to go to the vendor website to download drives for the mouse.  All of this assumes that the mouse works at all - please try the same mouse / receiver pair in another PC.  It's easy to misplace or confuse receivers for different devices.